# spaCY lemmatizer different results on repeated words

Tags: nlp, spacy, lemmatization

The lemmatization of the following sentence

- "Not finished! Not finished! A gem for our adopted daughter, Kiri, - - born of Grace's avatar, - - and whose conception was a complete mystery."*

has given a little bit confusing result

['not', 'finished', 'not', 'finish', 'a', 'gem', 'for', 'our', 'adopt', 'daughter', 'bear', 'of', 'avatar', 'and', 'whose', 'conception', 'be', 'a', 'complete', 'mystery']

The thing is that first word "finished" and "second" word "finished" were detected as different POS.

['PART', 'AUX', 'PART', 'VERB', 'DET', 'NOUN', 'ADP', 'PRON', 'VERB', 'NOUN', 'PROPN', 'VERB', 'ADP', 'PROPN', 'NOUN', 'CCONJ', 'DET', 'NOUN', 'AUX', 'DET', 'ADJ', 'NOUN']

First one was detected as an auxilary, and the second one was detected as a verb, as had been expected.

Adding third "Not finished!" gave the followinf result:

['not', 'finish', 'not', 'finish', 'not', 'finish', 'a', 'gem', 'for', 'our', 'adopt', 'daughter', 'bear', 'of', 'avatar', 'and', 'whose', 'conception', 'be', 'a', 'complete', 'mystery']

Removing one of them

['not', 'finish', 'a', 'gem', 'for', 'our', 'adopt', 'daughter', 'bear', 'of', 'avatar', 'and', 'whose', 'conception', 'be', 'a', 'complete', 'mystery']

Even four repetition let to get the expected result

['not', 'finish', 'not', 'finish', 'not', 'finish', 'not', 'finish', 'a', 'gem', 'for', 'our', 'adopt', 'daughter', 'bear', 'of', 'avatar', 'and', 'whose', 'conception', 'be', 'a', 'complete', 'mystery']

I find it difficult to find both a logical explanation and a workaround that will allow solving the problem not only with a specific example.

Comment: What is your pipeline, can you add the code that produces this result to your question? I can't reproduce the problem now, when I run `nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")` and then `doc = nlp('"Not finished! Not finished! A gem for our adopted daughter, Kiri, - - born of Grace\'s avatar, - - and whose conception was a complete mystery."')` and then `[token.lemma_ for token in doc]` I get the correct result `['"', 'not', 'finish', '!', 'not', 'finish', '!', 'a', 'gem', 'for', 'our', 'adopt', 'daughter', ...]` with the POS `['PUNCT', 'PART', 'VERB', 'PUNCT', 'PART', 'VERB',...]`.

Comment: You know, after loading en_core_web_trf instead of en_core_web_sm the problem went.
And know I also can't reproduce it even using en_core_web_sm again.
But I'll try to reproduce and will publish the code.

Maybe, the punctuation removal also influences on the result. But know I use the old code variant iand become correct result, as yours but withount PUNCT.

Comment: While using default pipeline nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm') I've reproduced the problem again. 
The problem can be solved by excluding parser
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm', disable=['parser'])

Comment: the code is the easiest one
doc = self._nlp(text)
[token.pos_ for token in doc]
[token.lemma_ for token in doc]

Comment: deactivating **tagger** I've got other issues. For instance, _sing_ was processed into _se_